# How to directly vectorize a function that takes indices as an input and returns a 2x2 np.array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let's say I have a function `f(i,j,a)` that takes the row and column from a 2D-numPy array `a` and returns another 2 x 2 numPy array with `i,j` at the top left corner  `b`i.e

```
def f(i,j,a):
 b = a[np.arange(2)[:, np.newaxis]  + i, np.arange(2) + j]
 return b
```

(The above code could be generalized by replacing the 2 with some other number). I want to vectorize this process by defining `f(i_array,j_array,a)` by essentially iterating over the `i,j`. This is simple with list comprehension:

`b_array = np.array([ f(i,j,a) for i in i_array, for j in j_array])`.

Is there a more efficient way to do this directly with numPy functions/indexing or is list comprehension the best I can do? I know that `np.vectorize` does this but I don't believe it is any faster than a simple list comprehension.

Comment: This can be done, but you should provide an example of what you want to do.

Comment: Thrre isn't a way to do this with an unknown `f`.  True 'vectorization means rewriting `f` so it works directly with `i_array`, `j_array`.  Usually that means making full use of array `broadcasting` and other compiled numpy methods.  As long as `f` has to be called once for each scalar `i,j` pair of values you are stuck with python iteration speeds.

Comment: @jared I added more context for the exact problem. Let me know if you want more information

Comment: In that indexing of `a`, the arrays `broadcast` with each other.  I can't offhand visualize whet you trying to do, but suspect index arrays like `np.arange(2)+i_array[:, None]` will be useful.  You want to select all the desired values from `a` with one expression using the i and j arrays, not with i and j iteratively.

Comment: `f` cannot be auto-vectorized (efficiently) *by Numpy* because it requires transforming `f` and/or (re)compiling so to do that, and Numpy is not able of such a thing. Compilation-based tools like Numpy/Cython can do that, but they will certainly not be efficient without modifying `f` anyway. Using such tools and rewriting `f` should result in a fast code. With Numpy you need big temporary arrays for the indexing which will make the computation relatively slow (though certainly much better than a scalar one). It is hard to help you more without knowing what is `a`.

Comment: If you're willing to use other packages, there is the [vmap](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.vmap.html#jax.vmap) function in [JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which does exactly this

Comment: The sliding windiw view might be useful here, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html.  It would make a (n,m,2,2) view, from which you could index .`[i_array, j_array,:,:]`.  If `a` isn't too large you could also reshape to (n,2,m,2), and transpose to (n,m,2,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (but my solution is a bit janky so any revisions would be appreciated). My code looks like:

```
import numpy as np

def f(i_array,j_array, a):
 i_transposed, j_transposed = i_array.T, j_array.T
 i_matrix = np.arange(2)[:, np.newaxis][:, np.newaxis]+ i_transposed
 j_matrix = np.arange(2)[:, np.newaxis]+ j_transposed
 b_grids = np.swapaxes(grid[i_matrix, j_matrix].T, 1,2)

 return b_grids
```

Here, we take advantage of broadcasting to generate a `np.array` of the previous matrix. The `i_matrix` term takes the  `np.arange(2)`, increases its dimension by 2 and uses broadcasting to make a `(2, 1, 2)` array with all the possible `i_transposed` added to 2. The same happens with `j_matrix` except it is 1 dimension lower. Then we use numPy indexing to broadcast in `grid[i_matrix, j_matrix]`. The dimensions are wrong because of the way we broadcasted and so we have to use `np.swapaxes.`

This should work somewhat more generally by replacing `np.arange(2)`  with whatever offset you want your coordinates to have.